# Responsive Layout: Zoom out a whole page element without using iframe or canvas

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to render a whole page(without body) element inside an element such that the parent element should render the zoomed-out version of the whole page.

**Whole Page**

```
<body>
<div class="fullpage">{pageHTMLWithoutBody}</div>
</body>
```

```
<div class="smallpage">
{pageHTMLWithoutBody}
</div>
```

Example:

**Full Page:**

[image: Full Page]

The above page should get shrinked and rendered as the following

**Small Page:**

[image: Small Page]

Right now, I've given relative sizing for the layout and the font by using `em` sizing.

```
.pageEle{
   padding: 2.5em; // instead of px or rem
}

.fullpage{
  font-size: 16px;
}

.smallpage {
  font-size: 10px; // Depends on Zoom level
}
```

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/shiva3/full/YzjYOZv)

But this is quite hard to follow especially for setting margin and padding for elements.
Is there any other way I could able to work with this apart from setting `font-size`?

I've tried zoom css property but it is not a recommended way and it also doesn't work on firefox.

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for `transform: scale(.5)` or something? Transform change your entire rendered box of the element and scales _absolutely_ everything inside it equally.

Comment: scale adds additional margins. I want the page to fit into my content without creating additional space

Comment: There is no way to universally control a page otherwise. The best way might be a web component wich contains your page in an element that you can scale to any size and then calculate the transform to fit it. Due to the difference in units  and `vw` and `vh` being related to the full page viewport, there is no way to fully do this the way you want to without having full control of the contents. If you do have full control of the contents, I think this idea might be redundant to begin with.

Comment: I do have full control over the page but the inside page X should also work independently irrespective of where it's rendered. **I was able to "zoom out" and render the page by making use of font size** but I find it hard to use relative values since the inside page "X" can have some elements styled using pixels(absolute values).